# Which varieties of Aurelia aurita do not have a polyp phase?

Tags: zoology, reproduction, development, marine-biology, invertebrates

According to [this](http://bioweb.uwlax.edu/bio203/s2007/shull_step/lifecyclerepro.htm) "In some *Aurelia aurita*, the polyp stage does not exist.", but they don't cite anything. Is there a resource detailing life cycles of various jellyfish or do I have to find their list and search articles one by one?

Comment: I've edited your post to correct some formatting and improve the tags (please avoid creating new tags unless they fit many questions). I also replaced species with varieties in your title, since it doesn't make sense to talk about species within a species. ———  Also note that questions are better received here if they demonstrate that you have a done a significant amount of prior research — for example you could [edit] your question to tell us where you've looked for answers (other than the original website), what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions.